# Specialize base class with template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, variadic-templates

I bang my head against the following code:

```
template<class... Ts> struct typelist{};

template<class S> struct Fun;

template<template<class...> class S, class... Ts>
struct Fun<S<Ts...>> {
    std::tuple<Ts...> _fun;
};

template<class S, class P> struct Gun;

template<template<class...> class S, class... Ts, class P>
struct Gun<S<Ts...>, P>: Fun<S<Ts...>>{
    auto hun(){
        std::cout << std::get<0>(_fun); // error: use of undeclared identifier '_fun'
    }
};

auto main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])-> int {
    auto gun = Gun<typelist<int>, float>{};
    gun.hun();
    return 0;
}
```

I do not get what is going on here and why I am getting that error. There must be smth obvious I do not see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the base class is dependent on the template parameters, and `_fun` is a nondependent name, which won't be looked up in dependent base classes.

You could make the name `_fun` dependent then it'll be looked up at the time of instantiation; at that time the exact base specialization is known.

e.g.

```
std::cout << std::get<0>(this->_fun);
//                       ~~~~~~
std::cout << std::get<0>(Fun<S<Ts...>>::_fun);
//                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: yep. I forgot quite some details while not actively coding. Thanks a lot.